# How to Select the Maximum value occurring 2 times?

Tags: t-sql

Suppose I have a table of values looking like this:

```
   Sample_Number | 
-------------------
    1             |
    1             |
    2             |
    3             |
    3             |
    4             |
    5             |
```

How can I write a SELECT statement to return the maximum sample number that occurs exactly 2 times? In the sample data the value I am looking for would be 3.

I imagine there could be a number of answers to this - I am especially interested in a solution with no inner selects and that uses the Having clause (if this is possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Sample_Number As MaxSampleNumberThatOccursTwice
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY Sample_Number
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY Sample_Number DESC
```

Comment: It works. Is there no way to do it with combination of MAX(Sample_Number) and Count - avoiding the TOP and ORDER BY?

Comment: @Mr.Blonde: only with a subquery or sommon.table-expression as shown in other answers. But why don't you want to use `TOP 1`?

Comment: From performance perspective - by not having to order the data. What would you recommend as the better performing solution? Yours or the proposal with a sub-select? Maybe it is milliseconds, but I try to use the best performing sql in all situations.

Comment: You want the highest number, a sort is inevitable.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there's an easier way to do this, but you can do it by pulling all of the `Sample_Number`s with exactly two entries, and pulling the `MAX()` of those values:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  Sample_Number
    From    Test
    Group By Sample_Number
    Having  Count(Sample_Number) = 2
) 
Select  Max(Sample_Number)
From    Cte
```

Comment: Also a working solution. What solution should I choose from a performance perspective?

Comment: From a performance-perspective, I'd go with Tim's answer.  But both the CTE/Sub-select and `TOP 1 ORDER BY` queries will be good performance-wise.

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte
as
(select sample_number
from #temp
group by Sample_Number 
having
count(Analysis_ID)=2
)
select max(sample_number) from cte
```

Comment: This will return both `1` and `3` in the resultset because of the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Your answer would work in my previous sample code. Please look at my edited sample data, as I would like to do it without that second column (now deleted).

Comment: @Siyual fixed uit

Comment: @Siyual can you please explain why the MAX(sample_number) did not take care of that?

Comment: @Twinkles Because the `GROUP BY` would give you the `MAX(Sample_Number)` per group, essentially giving you the distinct `Sample_Number`s that had exactly two entries.

Comment: @Twinkles:they are already segregated per group,here 1 is a group and 3 is a group

Answer (score 1):

I would use subselect:

```
SELECT MAX (sample_number) 
FROM  (SELECT sample_number
        FROM TAB1
        GROUP BY sample_number
        HAVING COUNT(sample_number) =2 
        )
```

Comment: This also works. I was hoping to avoid the sub-select though.

Answer (score 0):

Group by the Sample_Number and get the count of the group
and only select if the count is 2

```
select Sample_Number, count(*) count from someTable
group by Sample_Number
having count=2
```

Comment: This will return all sample numbers with count = 2. I need a single value, namely the maximum sample number.